# Streaming data from apache kafka to apache spark and then to elasticsearch in ubuntu

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I want to read data from an apache kafka topic through apache spark with a python script and then perform some operations on the data and then stream it to elasticsearch in real time ; ultimately i will build a model to perform on the data and the send it to elasticsearch in real time .

I am testing the pipeline if its working , i read data from apache kafka with a python script running in console in apache spark : the data appear in the console ; but when i added in the script to send the data to elasticsearch i am having compatibility issues with the Elasticsearch Spark connector .
the command to submit the script is :

```
/mnt/spark/bin/spark-submit   --master local[*]   --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:8.11.1   spark-consumer.py
```

apache spark version : 3.5.0
elasticsearch version : 8.11.1

the error when running the submission :

```
23/11/16 09:42:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/11/16 09:42:39 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
23/11/16 09:42:39 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = ef381904-3320-4d3f-958f-33290e44614f, runId = 8b4205bb-cad5-4e35-967a-4ee8016faa4e] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.16.27.221 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2451)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$3(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:70)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.addBatch(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:311)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(StreamExecution.scala:211)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sparkkafka/spark-consumer.py", line 106, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
  File "/mnt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming/query.py", line 221, in awaitTermination
  File "/mnt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/mnt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = ef381904-3320-4d3f-958f-33290e44614f, runId = 8b4205bb-cad5-4e35-967a-4ee8016faa4e] terminated with exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.16.27.221 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @Paulo i will add the error to the question