# Getting some logs from kafka topic into spark and the sending it to elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to send some data from apache kafka to elasticsearch through apache spark , for now i am testing the pipeline but still getting some errors , ultimately i will build a machine learning model to do prediction on incoming data inside spark and send the results along with the data .

this is my code for consuming and sending the data :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JsonLogs").getOrCreate()

kafka_bootstrap_servers = "172.16.27.221:9092"
kafka_topic = "winlogbeat"

logs_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
    .load()

logs_df = logs_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

query = logs_df.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .option("es.nodes", "172.16.27.221") \
    .option("es.port", "9200") \
    .option("es.resource", "testkafkaspark") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/sparkkafka/checkpointtest") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

And the command line to submit the python script is :

```
/mnt/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0 10_2.12:3.5.0,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:8.11.1 testt.py
```

And this is the error i am getting :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/11/17 10:35:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.16.27.221 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

23/11/17 10:35:10 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
23/11/17 10:35:10 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
23/11/17 10:35:10 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
23/11/17 10:35:10 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage cancelled: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.16.27.221 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
23/11/17 10:35:10 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) failed in 0.376 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.16.27.221 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
23/11/17 10:35:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 0.424839 s
23/11/17 10:35:10 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = c98987d0-b715-4362-844f-baf99a9e87e3, runId = 9b257ad3-1d7e-4e67-b0e8-ed06ef6d66e5] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.16.27.221 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2451)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$3(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:70)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.addBatch(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:311)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(StreamExecution.scala:211)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/11/17 10:35:10 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Async log purge executor pool for query [id = c98987d0-b715-4362-844f-baf99a9e87e3, runId = 9b257ad3-1d7e-4e67-b0e8-ed06ef6d66e5] has been shutdown
```

elasticsearch version 8.11.1
spark version 3.5.0
scala version : 2.12.18
apache version 3.6.0

P.S:
When i send data from apache kafka to spark , i can consume it and write to a file , and also when trying to send some test data from spark to elasticsearch the index is created and the data is available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Streaming data from apache kafka to apache spark and then to elasticsearch in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494101/streaming-data-from-apache-kafka-to-apache-spark-and-then-to-elasticsearch-in-ub)

Comment: @Paulo i didnt find any answer , it was me who asked that question yesterday so i added some clarification into my problem in this new question